# High error due to resample function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, wavelet, transform

I am working on training the output of the wavelet transform of a signal using a neural network in MATLAB. So I decided to use `3` layer `db4` wave filter for its wavelet transform. I have used an array of `240` elements and after wavelet transform, I get an array `l`

```
l = [36;36;65;123;240]
```

Now, since I have to train my neural network, I have to resample the wavelet transforms of length `36, 36, 65, 123` to an array of 240 elements.

So what I did was, I did wavelet transform of the signal. I resampled each wavelet transform to `240` points, and then resampled the wavelet to `36, 36, 65, 123` points respectively. I got an error of `20.2668`. What can be done to reduce error?

I used the following command to resample using MATLAB:

```
[c1, l] = wavedec(signal, 3, 'db4');

c1a = c1(1:l(1));
c1a = resample(c1a, length(signal), length(c1a));

c1b = c1(1+l(1):l(1)+l(2));
c1b = resample(c1b, length(signal), length(c1b));

c1c = c1(1+l(1)+l(2):l(1)+l(2)+l(3));
c1c = resample(c1c, length(signal), length(c1c));

c1d = c1(1+l(1)+l(2)+l(3):l(1)+l(2)+l(3)+l(4));
c1d = resample(c1d, length(signal), length(c1d));

c2a = resample(c1a, l(1), length(c1a));
c2b = resample(c1b, l(2), length(c1b));
c2c = resample(c1c, l(3), length(c1c));
c2d = resample(c1d, l(4), length(c1d));

X = waverec([c2a; c2b; c2c; c2d], l, 'db4');
err = norm(X-signal)
```

Now, the error err is reported as

```
err = 20.26688
```

What can I do to reduce this error? 
Please help :)

Comment: Resample has a 4th and 5th argument that can be used to improve accuracy at the expense of computation time.

Comment: Could you give an example for the same?